# PL/SQL Exception not catching the exception

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can you guys please help me understand why is my code not handling the exceptions and instead giving an error.

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DEFINE p_salary

DECLARE
v_fname employees.first_name%TYPE;
v_lname employees.last_name%TYPE;
v_salary employees.salary%TYPE := &p_salary;

BEGIN
SELECT first_name, last_name
INTO v_fname, v_lname
FROM employees
WHERE salary = v_salary;

INSERT INTO messages(results)
VALUES(v_fname || ' ' 
               || v_lname 
               || ' is the only employee with the salary of '
               || v_salary);

EXCEPTION
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    INSERT INTO messages(results)
    VALUES('More than one employee with a salary of ' || v_salary);

WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO messages(results) 
    VALUES('No employee with the salary of ' || v_salary);

WHEN OTHERS THEN
    INSERT INTO messages(results)
    VALUES('Some other error occurred.');

END;
/SQL> SQL> SP2-0135: symbol p_salary is UNDEFINED
SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   
15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   
31   32  
Enter value for p_salary: 6000
old   4:     v_salary employees.salary%TYPE := &p_salary;
new   4:     v_salary employees.salary%TYPE := 6000;
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 20
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

The error is something that I have put in the exception block and still it does not get captured.

Comment: This code works as expected; I modified it, slightly, so that it runs on Scott's schema. However, what you posted isn't entirely true. The first line shows the "SQL>" prompt which implies that you ran it in SQLPlus. Subsequent (and unnecessary) DEFINE, nor any of lines that follow don't show prompt nor line numbers. So, how exactly did you run that code? It would help if you posted tables' description (where does the INVALID NUMBER come from?), as well as copy/paste real SQLPlus session, not fabricated one.

Comment: How many rows foe the SELECT INTO return? Just wandering where the `ORA-01422` comes from.

Comment: Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a926d8/3) which shows your code works as expected. So the results you claim to get come from somewhere else. If you want our help you need to post a reproducible test case, which means table structures and sample data too.

Comment: @Littlefoot: I've been able to recreate the OP's output using SQL\*Plus; I doubt they've fabricated it.  The bunched-up appearance of line numbers all on the same line is what you get when you paste a load of text  into SQL\*Plus in a Linux shell window.  (I'm using openSUSE but I imagine other distributions behave similarly.)

Comment: @APC: here's a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da6581/2) that does reproduce the error.

Comment: Aha, Linux. Got it. Thank you, @Luke. I saw you - probably - figured out what's going on. Let's see what the OP says about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to insert logging messages into a column of a table that only accepts numbers.

The `exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` exception is being caught, but there is another exception raised while handling the original exception, so it seems they both get raised together.

You don't give the definition of your `messages` table, but I was able to reproduce your error if I created it using `create table messages (results number);`.

You will need to either (a) change the type of the `results` column to, say, `VARCHAR2(4000)` using something like

```
alter table messages modify results varchar2(4000);
```

or (b) use a different column within this table.

Comment: Yeah my results column was defined as number(10). Thanks a lot for the help, I was getting so mad not able to figure it out. You calmed my anxiety!!! :P